# HTML File Upload Control Problem in Asp.net 2003

Tags: c#, asp.net

hi im using html File Upload Control in Asp.net 2003 version...whenever I try to upload the file its working fine...but suppose I upload the file then I click any radio button or any other button, fileupload control value is automatically erased..so I cannot upload the file successfully...anybody help me...

Comment: Are you saving the file after uploading it?  Are there any partial postbacks?  I don't understand how you're saying its uploaded fine, but you click a button and its gone.  Are you saying the button deletes from the server?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know; fileUpload control does not keep the value for browse during the other controls postbacks, for security reasons.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/968251/retain-value-in-fileupload-control) may give you a hint.