# UpdatePanel - No errors, but web.config settings required?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel, postback

I'm having issues getting UpdatePanel working in a large, existing solution. I have a sample page (below), which works in a freshly created *demo* website, but not when added to the existing *target* website.

The functionality is to isolate a dropdown's auto-postback, so I don't lose the contents of a **FileUpload** ASP control (it does this for [security reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/968251/retain-value-in-fileupload-control), with some solutions [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239397/asp-net-keep-fileupload-after-postback))

In the *target* (non-demo) site, the control adds to the page fine (inc intellisense), and the page renders - but changing the drop down still performs a postback, rather than ajax-ifying the dropdown box.

The *target* solution mentioned was previously upgraded from ASP.NET v1.1, **so I'm wondering if there's something I'm missing in the configuration?**

The only difference I can find in the rendered HTML source is that the non-working version doesn't add the **PageRequestManager**, e.g.:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
//<![CDATA[
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._initialize('ctl02', document.getElementById('form1'));
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance()._updateControls(['tctl03'], [], [], 90);
//]]>
</script>
```

Sample page:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager2" runat="server" />
    <div>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="TestDropDown" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="TestDropDown_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    <asp:ListItem>One</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Two</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Three</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>

                <asp:Literal runat="server" Text="Original state" ID="litText" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>

        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload2" runat="server" />
    </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And in the code behind:

```
protected void TestDropDown_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        litText.Text = "Ajax update. The file details should still be present below";
    }
```

I can confirm that the ScriptManager tag adds the following to the page source, so I assume the Ajax Toolkit has been added:

```
if (typeof(Sys) === 'undefined') throw new Error('ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load.');
```

And that we have the following sections in web.config:

```
<compilation defaultLanguage="c#" debug="true">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>

[...]

<pages>
    <controls>
    <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, [...]
    <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions" [...]

[...]

<httpHandlers>
  <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
  <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
</httpHandlers>
<httpModules>
  <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
</httpModules>
```

The sample works in the *demo* site without the <Triggers> section, but I've tried adding it to the *target* site, to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the following should **not** be set in web.config, and occurs as a result of the upgrade from ASP.NET v1.1:

```
<xhtmlConformance mode="Legacy"/>
```

As discussed on [ScottGu's blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/12/10/gotcha-don-t-use-xhtmlconformance-mode-legacy-with-asp-net-ajax.aspx)